# Error no internet connection when using volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i am using volley to load my listview items.However i dont know how to include this code to show when there is error in internet connection before the loading progress starts.
Here is the code snippet i want to add:

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

    /* DO WHATEVER YOU WANT IF INTERNET IS AVAILABLE */

    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("No Internet");
        builder.setMessage("Internet is required. Please Retry.");

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                InitiateDownload();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); // calling builder.create after adding buttons
        dialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And here is my activity:

```
public class Movies extends ActionBarActivity{
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event);

     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent newActivity2=new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, newActivity2);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (error.networkResponse==null){
                     if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)){
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bummer.No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }}}
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
ParseApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) { 

            Intent intent = new Intent(Movies.this, Detail.class);     
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        });}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



    }
```

Is there some way to insert the code into this activity or is there another way?thanks in advance guys.

Comment: It's a duplicate, specifically the answer to this question seems to be a copy paste from the answer linked above. I flagged as duplicate, as I should. That comment is auto-generated. The likelihood of this question actually being closed is slim, but it is beneficial to others to provide alternate sources of information. No harm intended, no harm done. This post may rest.

Comment: Nothing is ever dead on Stack Overflow..

Comment: That's great, I agree. I guess the duplicatation of answers was possible back then because now stackoverflow flags these to avoid copy pasting.